# Run 1.5 miles under 10 mins, considered hiit?

Tags: running

Is running with that speed, continuously, not in intervals, considered as hiit? 
And does it develop fast or slow twitch muscles, or both?

Comment: Please add some details. Tell us if the run is broken up into smaller intervals, give us an average running speed, tell us about your current physical shape etc. This question is entirely too broad.

Comment: I would "sprint" or run as fast as I can continuously, speed can vary, but doesn't dip to a jog, until I complete 1.5 miles under 10 minutes. Average running speed would be around 0.15 miles per minute. It's not a slow run, nor is it a long run, pretty intense, so is an exercise at this intensity closer to hiit or endurance run, or both?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HIIT training is a form of workout where you alternate between about 30-60 second periods of intense exercise and less intense exercise, so running at a constant speed would not be considered HIIT. Running usually falls under the category of cardio.

Slow twitch muscles are developed when doing endurance exercise and fast twitch muscles are developed when doing exercise that requires quick, powerful movements. I would personally say that running falls in the category of slow twitch muscles, as you are constantly exercising your legs over an extended period of time.

Comment: What if the run was a very fast one, though not done in intervals, and doesn't dip to a jog, and the distance is not that long? I'm not sure if it's fair to use the words "fast" and "not that long" though.

Comment: @user32581 If it's at a sprinting pace and lasts for about 5-10 minutes, it would be classed as hypertrophy (the building of muscles).

Comment: @user32581 Linking on to the above comment, it would also be classed as cardio/endurance. Probably more so than hypertrophy.